# Logback level element vs. level attribute

Tags: logback, slf4j, logback-classic

The question is simple. In some logback.xmls I see level as an element:

```
<logger name="mylog" additivity="false">
  <level value="DEBUG" />
  <appender-ref ref="fileAppender" />
</logger>
```

But in some it is written as an attribute:

```
<logger name="mylog" additivity="false" level="debug">
  <appender-ref ref="fileAppender" />
</logger>
```

What is the difference?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of configuring Logback, there is no difference. Both of the following declarations are functionally identical:

```
<logger name="com.x.y">
    <level value="DEBUG"/>
</logger>

<logger name="com.x.y" level="DEBUG" />
```

Logback's configurer (have a look at `ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure()`) creates an identical `Logger` instance for both of these declarations.

The only difference - when parsing the configuration - is that the first one manifests in more instances of `ch.qos.logback.core.joran.event.SaxEvent` (start and end events for the logger and for the level) than the second one (start and end events for the logger only).

If you are associating a logger with a specific appender then you'll already be defining a logger element body e.g.

```
<logger name="com.x.y">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
</logger>
```

In which case defining a `level` within the element body rather than as an attribute might read better but it really is just a case of developer preference.

Comment: Good to know since the documentation only presents the second way.

Comment: Do you know what happens if both are used?